# in bluebird nodejs when should i use .error() instead of .catch

Tags: node.js, bluebird

In bluebird **nodejs** when should i use .error() instead of .catch.

What is difference between them.  Please Explain in brief.

```
promise()
.then()
.error() OR
.catch()
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation? What you do not understand? http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/error.html

Comment: When there's documentation that explains the precise difference between the `.error()` and `.catch()`, your question should be about something different than "what's the difference" because the documentation already pretty clearly shows the difference, with a very good example.  It seems like you're asking us to go find the documentation for you.  If there's something in that documentation that you don't understand, then your question should be about that.

Comment: i  read the docs . But was still having doubt that's why is asked question.

Comment: And read my question watchfully . I am asking when should i use either of one and then asked difference. People may have doubts after reading docs . Accept this fact. If you read anythng that doesnt mean you understand everythng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.catch`:

- Catches all errors and is also ES6 [standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch)

`.error`:

- Only catches when error is instance of [`Error`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error)
- is a convenience method in [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/error.html)

<strike>Many libraries don't throw error which is instance of `Error`, so you are better off using `.catch`</strike>

Some library or user code may not throw error which is instanceOf `Error`. Although it is recommended to throw `Error` (or subclass) instance but there is nothing stopping to do otherwise.

From http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/catch.html:

> Like `.catch` but instead of catching all types of exceptions, it only catches operational errors.
>   Note, "errors" mean errors, as in objects that are instanceof Error - not strings, numbers and so on. See a string is not an error.

Some instances where error was not instance of `Error`. They have been fixed.

1. https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis/issues/374
2. https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/345

Answer (score 0):

```
Whenever Dealing with bluebird think about the asynchronous call of 
try{
    }catch(){
    } block
    function doSomeWork() {
      return Promise.try(function() {

        return request.get(url).then(function(response) {
          // ... do some specific work
        });

      }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log("Some specific work failed", err);
        throw err; // IMPORTANT! throw unless you intend to suppress the error
      });
    }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.